# Excel user defined function doesn't work properly when used in SUMIFS function

Tags: excel, vba

I have defined the function:

```
Function TabName()
    TabName = ActiveSheet.Name
End Function
```

When I type `=TabName()` into a cell, I get the text `tabname` in the cell, as you can see here:

[image: function does what it should do]

But when I use the function in a cell like this:

[image: Function doesn't work properly]

I get the wrong result. The correct result is what I get if I "hardcode" the tab name in like in this screenshot:

[image: Hardcoded]

Why is this, and what can I do to make my function work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the wrong result because your `=SUMIFS()` compares values to **string value** `"=tabname()"`, not the **result of function** `tabname()`. Try this:

```
=SUMIFS(Bokningar!E:E;Bokningar!B:B;TabName())-SUM(C:C)
```